# Constructor and "this" pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, this

i started studying c++ and i found the class below in a tutorial. My question has to do with the constructor.
the class is:

```
class point{
private:
    double *x;
    double *y;
public:
    point(double x=1,double y=1);
    //....
};
```

and the constructor is:

```
point::point(double x,double y)
{
    this->x = new double;
    *(this->x)=x;
    this->y = new double;
    *(this->y)=y;

    }
```

i wanted to ask WHY is the following code wrong? why do i have to use "this"?

```
 point::point(double x,double y)
    {
        x = new double;
        *x=x;
        y = new double;
        *y=y;

    }
```

Comment: Please throw that tutorial into garbage.

Comment: Because when you refer to `x` the compiler thinks your referring to the parameter variable `x` and not the class variable `x`. and since paramater variable `x` is not a pointer it throws a compilation error

Comment: The example is very stupid. 1) because of duplicate of variable name `x` and `y` (members and parameters); 2) because `x` is not defined as `double` but pointer to `double`. Maybe the purpose is to give example, but pay attention to these notes.

Answer (score 4):

How would your compiler know the difference between `x` the parameter and `x` the field of the class ?

`this->x` means **the `x` variable that belongs to the class I'm in** i.e: the `point` class

If you called the field x in the class `_x`, you could write `*_x = x` in the constructor

PS: Yes, agreed with the comments, this is NOT a good tutorial x)

For more information : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this

Comment: I don't think the sentence "this->x means the x variable that belongs to the scope I'm in i.e: the point class" uses the correct terminology. `this` isn't about scope, it's about using the current object members **instead** of using the current scope (the function, which would find the function parameter `x`).

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was looking for a way to phrase it correctly.

Comment: Bad habbit x) Not sure where it comes from

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add bit additional information to Naliwe answer,
You can do the constructor like this:

```
 point::point(double x,double y) : 
              x(new double(x)), 
              y(new double(y))
 {
 }
```

In this case, the compiler *understands* which name refer which "thing" - e.g. first x is for class field, second is for constructor argument.

Comment: Thank you, I hesitated, because it involves other concepts, like the fact that using the constructor list, your fields aren't initialized 'twice' i.e default constructed then initialized to whatever you want :) Although in this particular case, he uses pointers

Comment: this is the preferable C++ way. however in this particular code there is an error that might lead to memory leak and / or program crash. in C++11 you should use smart pointers, but you will learn for them later.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might try using scope qualifiers:

```
point::point( double x, double y ) {
   point::x = new double;
   *point::x = x;
   point::y = new double;
   *point::y = y;
}
```